# how can i make grid (design) responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

i've tried everything to make this design responsive but i haven't got anything

Looking for some help or suggestion would be great..

Thank you

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bobharry/w1j7anvx/1/)

```
 <div class="box-section">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta sapiente, est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet.est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet. est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta sapiente, est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta sapiente, est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet.est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet. est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta sapiente, est, inventore maiores accusantium laudantium ratione. Veritatis sunt quidem earum corporis molestiae, soluta libero asperiores modi ipsam debitis alias eveniet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use bootstrap that will help you. It is easy to use. In your code you have to write some more css and also you want to write media query css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**media-queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this.

Here is an example how to use media-queries with your design:

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w1j7anvx/3/)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .box-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box-inner {
    padding: 25px;
  }
}
```

`(max-width: 600px)` means that when the screen/browser size has a width of `600px` *or less*, the following CSS rules will be applied or overwritten. So if you give your `.box-container` a width of 50%, and then a 100% in your media-query, `.box-container` will have a width of 50% until your screen/browser size hits 600px and then it will change to a width of 100%.

Comment: Hi. actually the problem is with the alignment ..four box is went down completely and am trying to make it right after the box .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you try explaining again?

Comment: That's a different question, but I found [**something**](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/01/18/css-grid-one-layout-method-not-the-only-layout-method/) that might really help. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Grid yet, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS out. If you want them all to be on the same row make their width:25%
Then adjust the min-width to your needs. Here is a link to how to use flex for responsive design.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.box-section {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    min-width:450px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

.box-inner {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Gilbert thanks but i don't want the boxes in the same row ..i mean i don't want space between the boxes ..you can see the extra space is coming after the 2nd box

Comment: Oh for sure! Check this out, and use media querys to adjust the boxes as needed when the view gets to a certaint size. 

https://jsfiddle.net/w1j7anvx/21/